# Sequelize update function expects all fields to be provided

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Am using Sequlize 5.8.5 and trying to update a model but, it doesn't seem to be possible unless all fields are provided. For example performing `Project.update(args)` where `args` cloud sometimes has a name field with changed value and sometimes not even passed at all, if the name field doesn't need to be updated, am getting an error such as `err:  { SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: projects.name cannot be null ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

This method is possible in Sequelize.  Here's a test I ran:

```
let u1 = {username : 'Test User', title_id: 4};
let u2 = {title_id: 4};

User.update(u1, {where : {id : 3}});
User.update(u2, {where : {id : 5}});
```

Here is the generated SQL:

```
Executing (default): UPDATE `muser` SET `username`='Test User',`title_id`=4 WHERE `id` = 3
Executing (default): UPDATE `muser` SET `title_id`=4 WHERE `id` = 5
```

How are you creating your `args` object?  The error suggests something like this: `let args = {field1 = null}` where `Project.field1` does not allow null values.